# tab completion in radare2 gives seg fault

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, reverse-engineering, radare2

I'm new to radare2 ans was previously using it on Ubuntu or Kali.
I switched to Manjaro 20.2 and noticed that whenever I press the [TAB] it ends up in a segmentation fault something like this:

```
>> r2 hello
[0x00001040]> aa
[x] Analyze all flags starting with sym. and entry0 (aa)
[0x00001040]> afl
0x00001040    1 47           entry0
0x00001070    4 41   -> 34   sym.deregister_tm_clones
0x000010a0    4 57   -> 51   sym.register_tm_clones
0x000010e0    5 65   -> 55   sym.__do_global_dtors_aux
0x00001130    1 9            entry.init0
0x00001000    3 27           sym._init
0x000011c0    1 5            sym.__libc_csu_fini
0x000011c8    1 13           sym._fini
0x00001150    4 101          sym.__libc_csu_init
0x00001139    1 23           main
0x00001030    1 6            sym.imp.puts
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

source code for hello:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {
    printf("Hello World\n");
    return 0;
}
```

the last line where I got the seg fault, i had initially typed:

```
> s mai[TAB]
```

so the whole line was replaced with blank, and about a second later the segfault and radare2 process was killed.

I did update radare2 with `r2pm update`, and also cloned the repo and reinstalled, but did not help.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: It is good practice to check and include your version of Radare2 in your question. You can check your version via: `user@host:~$ r2 -v`. If you installed Radare2 via a package manager, such as `user@host:~$ sudo apt install radare2`, I recommend uninstalling that version and installing via the official git repo: `user@host:~$ git clone https://github.com/radareorg/radare2.git`.  The version when installed via git will look similar to: `radare2 4.6.0-git 0 @ linux-x86-64 git`.

Comment: yep, i read about this earlier. i had initially installed using snap. But then read about issues that were caused and installed via the official git repo. currently its at version 5.0.0. I use the same version on wsl on my windows and it works fine. I really don't know what the issue is